# Transaction status marks Success but don't have Tokens Transferred

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, tokens, etherscan

when I checked some transactions I found sometimes transaction mark success but can't see any info like Token Transfer. In this case, do you know what type of this transaction ?

[image]

Comment: Can you also share the transaction hash as plain text?

Comment: yeb, many trans like this: 0xbc82a618e5b57fbe51a5ac9d29c9853fab9b21099152bb4772193cd16006eff3